# What is the meaning of "cleaving" a material?

Tags: terminology, material-science, definition, optical-materials

When reading "Modern techniques of Surface Science" by D.P. Woodruff, it is stated that:

*"The main methods used to achieve this in situ cleaning are (...)cleavage."*

This is in the context of requirements for studies of properties of ideal surfaces, as an extra step before requiring UHV (Ultra-high vacuum).
It is also mentioned that some materials cleave readily. **What is the concept of cleaving of surfaces?**

When looking for it, the Wikipedia article states that:

*"Cleavage (...)is the tendency of crystalline materials to split along definite crystallographic structural planes."*

Is this the same type of cleavage as meant in the Nanosurfaces, and surfaces context? Or is this something completely different?

Comment: I think it simply means to separate cleanly along a crystalline plane, as opposed to other things such as cutting or anything which leaves an irregular edge.

Comment: But how is that separation achieved? Thank you for your help

Comment: "To cleave" is an odd verb in English. It can mean both to split apart and to cling together!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on the material, but when I was researching 2D semiconductors, we actually just used Scotch tape. You press a piece of tape down firmly onto the surface of your sample and then slowly peel it away. The sample ends up being cleaved as several layers from the top separate from the bottom of the sample. (This happens because these samples were similar to graphite: strong bonding in the plane, but only weakly attached vertically.)

The reason for cleaving samples first is to get a fresh surface that isn't oxidized or covered in junk from the air. After cleaving, samples are loaded into UHV as quickly as possible to keep them clean.

Comment: There have been any number of clever devices built to cleave samples inside a UHV chamber as well.

Comment: Interesting! We also used a different kind of tape inside the chamber. Rolled it up and attached it to the sample, and then used a manipulator to remove the tape inside the chamber. Low-tech solutions were good enough for us ;)

Answer (score 1):

To cleave a crystal, one provides a little defect at the edge (a nick, for example), then applies some pressure at that point. Pressure causes the defect to propagate, cleaving the crystal along a crystalline axis. This is a common method to cut crystals because it’s easy, relatively controllable, and leaves an ideally flat and clean surface. It’s also a standard way to [chop up a wafer](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MxjppY1iA4A).